# Modify Master View of Fiori Purchase Requisition APp

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to modify the master view (S2.view.xml) of the Fiori Purchase Req Approval App.  I need to add a footer to this view. I tried adding footer to the S2 view XML but it didnt work. So looked like the S2 controller, getHeaderFooter() needs modification. My questions

1) Is this a standard method? Why is it added to the controller

2) If I have to add footer, how do I add it to the  Master view???

3) How do I suppress the method in case required?

Appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: You seem to have already asked this question on SCN http://scn.sap.com/thread/3614602 - is that you? if so, please don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Is this a standard method? Why is it added to the controller

**You are supposed to override `getHeaderFooterOptions` in your controller.**

2) If I have to add footer, how do I add it to the Master view???

**The following code sample is to add two Buttons Test1 and Test2 to footer.**

```js
getHeaderFooterOptions : function() {
    var oOptions = {
        buttonList: [{
        sI18nBtnTxt: "Test1",
        onBtnPressed: function() {

        }
        }, {
        sI18nBtnTxt: "Test2",
        onBtnPressed: function(oEvent) {

        }
        }]
    };
    return oOptions;
},
```

**For details about overriding `getHeaderFooterOptions`, see the [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ca.scfld.md.controller.ScfldMasterController.html#getHeaderFooterOptions).**

3) How do I suppress the method in case required?

**You can't suppress the method.**

Comment: Thanks Allen - I tried this but it adds the button to the far right corner of the view. "test1" button is on the footer, but "test2" iopens up if you click. I need to put the other button directly on the footer?? Is that possible??

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. "The far right corner of the view" is part of the footer. what do you mean "test2" opens up if you click?

Comment: Hi allen, I wish I could add image here..So, I basically want to add few buttons on the Footer which should be displayed directly on the footer, and should not need any additional click to display the pop -up of buttons. I tried what you suggested, the test 1 displays correctly, but then a option is displayed like '...'. If you click on this option, then only'test 2' displayed as a pop-up.

Comment: This is because of the overflow behavior, the buttons are by default added to content-right of the footerbar, there is no way you can change it.

Comment: Thanks Allen, it makes sense now. How about the oPositiveAction  & oNegativeAction buttons? Even they will also be added to content-right??

Comment: its weird that the method add the overflow automatically. It should have the flexibility to display all the buttons in the toolbar and not in an actionsheet.

Comment: You can try oPositiveAction & oNegativeAction on your own to see the rendered result. One alternative is you can add one ActionSheet and position your two buttons in the ActionSheet.

Comment: hi Allen - Positive & Negative Aaction button didnt work. I added them correctly, but the controller didnt render them. So as of now, I am going for filter option, and on click - it opens up Button as action sheet. Thanks for your help